# Visual C++ Linux Development Environment, Raspbian, and nRF24L01 (RF24)

Tags: pi-2, nrf24l01

I recently discovered the [Visual C++ Linux Development Environment](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e), which allows to debug and release code from Visual Studio (on the PC) directly on the Pi (in my case on Raspbian Jessie).

Since I connected a nRF24L01 wireless chip to my Pi, I downloaded maniacbugs [RF24-library](https://tmrh20.github.io/RF24/RPi.html) for Raspbian in order to get it working. This is a C / C++ -library, which should be convenient for the Visual C++ LDE. In short, I was unable to debug or release a project on the Pi including the library (for example the gettingstarted.cpp -example). The problem lies within the linking of the library.

Therefore, I tried **approach number one**:

- I added the direction to the header-files into properties -> C / C++ -> Additional Include Directories
- I added the library direction to Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories as well as Linker -> Input -> Library Dependencies (wrote librfa24.a in it, I generated this .a file from all .o files inside the RF24-library)

Both steps were taken for release as well as debug mode.
Unfortunately, this error-message appears:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error       g++ exited with code 1, please see the Output Window - Build output for more details (NOTE: the build output verbosity might need to be changed in Tools Options to see more information in the Output Window). Project2    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.Common.targets  200 Build
```

Even more unfortunate is that the additional output promised by the error message cannot be displayed (an actual issue with the LDE until now).

This led to **approach number two**:

- I added all necessary files directly to the project (via Add item)
  (RF24.h, RF24.cpp, ..)

This actually works with one major problem: spi.h is unable to compile:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       unknown type name ‘class’   RF24_Project_2  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RF24_Project_2\RF24_Project_2\spi.h  43  
Error       expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘:’ token   RF24_Project_2  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RF24_Project_2\RF24_Project_2\spi.h  68  
Error       expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘:’ token   RF24_Project_2  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RF24_Project_2\RF24_Project_2\spi.h  73  
Error       expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘:’ token   RF24_Project_2  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RF24_Project_2\RF24_Project_2\spi.h  77  
Error       expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token   RF24_Project_2  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RF24_Project_2\RF24_Project_2\spi.h  22  
Error       expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token   RF24_Project_2  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RF24_Project_2\RF24_Project_2\spi.h  43  
Error       unknown type name ‘class’   RF24_Project_2  C:\Users\Desktop\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RF24_Project_2\RF24_Project_2\spi.h  22
```

This message (as I read on StackOverflow) results from comiler issues to differentiate between C and C++ files. Therefore, I also tried to explicitly compile this file in C++ - no success.

Now the **questions**:

- Has anybody any experience with creating software for the Pi in the LDE and has any idea about the linking problem?
- Even better: has anybody experience with creating code for the nRF24L01 with the LDE and could help with this problem?